# C# bitmaps causes memory leak

Tags: c#, image, memory-leaks, bitmap, garbage-collection

I have a simple application, which renders images and prints them out. In order to make it easy and convenient to design, I have used custom `Control`.

Now, I have a simple control of size 1800 x 2400 (yeah, pretty big):

```
public class PhotoControl : UserControl
{
    public PhotoControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And an extension class, which uses it for generating images:

```
public static class PhotoProcessor
{
    private static readonly PhotoControl PhotoForm = new PhotoControl(); // Single instance

    public static Image GenerateImage(this Photo photo)
    {
        PhotoForm.SetPhoto(photo); // Apply a photo

        Image result;
        
        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(PhotoForm.Width, PhotoForm.Height))
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height);
            PhotoForm.DrawToBitmap(b, r); // Draw control to bitmap

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png); // Save bitmap as PNG
                result = Image.FromStream(ms); 
            }
        }

        // GC.Collect();
        // GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        return result; // return
    }
```

Now, I try to generate 30 photos using this:

```
myPhoto.GenerateImage().Save(@"Output1.png", ImageFormat.Png);
myPhoto.GenerateImage().Save(@"Output2.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

I do not store the reference, I just save an image and expect that GC will collect these images after saving to a file.

It will take about 2 GB of memory, and finally throw an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Out of memory.

If I look at Visual Studio diagnostic tools, it looks like:

[image]

Let's take a snapshot, and look at the contents of the heap, we will see that there are many `MemoryStream`s:

[image]
[image]

What causes `MemoryStream` to produce a memory leak? As far as I know, `using()` generates `Dispose()` call, which should take care of it.

P.S. If I remove comment and call `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`, then it takes 2-3 times less memory, but it still grows - ~200 images will still kill an application.

Changing the image saving to the following:

```
Image img;

img = myPhoto.GenerateImage();
img.Save(@"Output1.png", ImageFormat.Png);
img.Dispose();

img = myPhoto.GenerateImage();
img.Save(@"Output2.png", ImageFormat.Png);
img.Dispose();
```

will produce the same result as using `GC.Collect();`. It will also take less memory, but not eliminate memory leakage.

Comment: Does `Image` not need to be disposed? You're returning it and never disposing

Comment: @Rob I guessed that not storing a reference to an image will make GC collect it. Anyway, using `Dispose` after saving doesn't solve the problem. I have updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is the place which produces the problem? `MemoryStream` size is always the same, but you are using different images (e.g. `Output1.png`, `Output2.png`). Could it be some other `MemoryStream`?

Comment: @Sinatr I have reproduced this problem in a blank project, which has nothing except for this `GenerateImage` calls. I guess, it always has the same size, because images are actually the same - look, I am always generating an image from `myPhoto` :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Would you be able to host the entire solution (the small one that reproduces the issue) somewhere? If I have some time tonight I could take a closer look (as well as others being able to)

Comment: @Rob Actually, disposing every image, as mentionted in the end of my question and using `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` at the same time, did help. Memory usage graph becomes a sinusoidal, and never exceeds ~300 MB :) Thank you very much! I mistakenly assumed that it will be disposed automatically if I do not store the reference to it. Could you post your suggestion so that I can accept is as a correct answer?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I've posted an answer, but I'm still a bit suspicious about needing to manually run the GC - seems like there may be another problem. Anyway, if you do find in the future that it's still causing an issue, ping me and I'll remove the answer or update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IDisposable` and thus must be disposed manually. You're currently returning an `Image` from `GenerateImage` but not disposing it after saving.